# partial toc for multiple parts

Tags: table-of-contents, parts, appendix

I want to create a table of contents for my large appendix, which consists of several `\parts`. I don't want any of the main text contents (i.e., can't use base `\tableofcontents`). The `minitoc` solution does not work, because it only defines partial TOCs for a `\part`, `\chapter`, or `\section`. The `etoc` package doesn't seem to work either, yielding a blank TOC (I think it also assumes `\part`s).

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{minitoc} % (1)
% \usepackage{etoc} % (2)
\begin{document}
  \section{Introduction}
  \vfill\hrule\vfill
  APPENDIX
  \appendix
  \renewcommand{\partname}{Appendix}
  \renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
  \counterwithin{section}{part}
  % \tableofcontents % (0) issue: "Introduction" is included
  % \parttoc % minitoc (1) issue: no TOC
  % \localtableofcontents % etoc (2) issue: empty TOC
  \vfill\hrule\vfill
  \part{Model Details}
  \section{Model Section}
  \part{Supplemental Results}
  \section{SR Section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a solution from `titletoc` from the `titlesec` bundle:

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc} % (3)
\begin{document}
  \section{Introduction}
  \vfill\hrule\vfill
  APPENDIX
  \appendix
  \renewcommand{\partname}{Appendix}
  \renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
  \counterwithin{section}{part}
  \startcontents[app] % titletoc: can do any scope
  \printcontents[app]{}{0}{} % print it
  \vfill\hrule\vfill
  \part{Model Details}
  \section{Model Section}
  \part{Supplemental Results}
  \section{SR Section}
\end{document}
```

#### Result

The spacing needs to be adjusted, but the scope of the TOC is correct.

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way with [`etoc`](https://ctan.org/etoc).  I had to fight a bit, because some things are counter-intuitive.  I understood from `etoc` documentation that `localtableofcontents` needs to be told where it resides and after some digging I found `\etocsetlocaltop.toc{}` command, but it seems to break if used as `\etocsetlocaltop.toc{-2}` (as `-1` is for parts) and one can not use either somestuff such as `\etocsetlocaltop.toc{document}`.  Maybe worthwile a report to `etoc` author.  Turns out `\etocsetlocaltop.toc{none}` works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
% \tableofcontents
  \section{Introduction}
  \vfill\hrule\vfill
  APPENDIX
  \appendix
  \renewcommand{\partname}{Appendix}
  \renewcommand{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}
  \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}
  \counterwithin{section}{part}
\etocsetlocaltop.toc{none}
\localtableofcontents
  \vfill\hrule\vfill
  \part{Model Details}
  \section{Model Section}
  \part{Supplemental Results}
  \section{SR Section}
\end{document}
```

[image: TOC with etoc]